# How to extract 95% data in python

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of numbers, I would like to drop outliers while preserving 95% of the total number of datapoints. E.g. range(0,100,1) would become range(2,98,1).

For example if the data is something like

```
[0.01,0.02,4,5,7,3,1,4,6,7,10000,10002] -> [4,5,7,3,1,4,6,7]
```

Is there any function in the Python standard library or Numpy for this purpose?

Comment: Do you really need a function for this purpose?
Write a = [0.01,0.02,4,5,7,3,1,4,6,7,10000,10002] and percentage = 0.95
And then write:
a[0:int(round(len(a)*percentage))]
I hope 95% means somehow 95% of items in the list.

Comment: And what 95%? Please clarify...

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by "95%"? It's not 95% of the data (`12 * .95 = 11`), nor is it the span of 2 stddevs (std = 3.7K).

Comment: Sorry my call to int() is redundant in the example cf. above.

Comment: Editied for clarity of meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in filtering out data that's within 95% of the [median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation), or MAD.

The MAD of this dataset is 2.5 (whereas the std deviation is >3000). We can use this to filter points that are more than 2 median deviations away (collecting approx ~95%)

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0.01,0.02,4,5,7,3,1,4,6,7,10000,10002])
deviations = 2

d = np.abs(data - np.median(data))
med_abs_dev = np.median(d)
s = d / med_abs_dev
filtered = data[s < deviations]
# [ 0.01  0.02  4.    5.    7.    3.    1.    4.    6.    7.  ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, from your example, seems 0.01 and 0.02 are still in list?

Comment: yes, because they are within the specified tolerance. you can decrease `deviations` to filter them out.

Comment: And I'm not sure whether my requirement is related with the 95%confidence intervals which could be calculated using  Mean-1.96*SE<x≤Mean+1.96*SE